# C# Application icon changing docked icon

Tags: c#

I have set the application icon under project properties Application tab, Resources, Icon and manifest to a custom icon.  However it only changes the icon I see before I open the application.  However when I open my application and look at the icon on my dock it is the same icon that I had when debugging with VS 2010.

Here is the image for the icon before I launch.

[image]

That is the icon that I want my docked icon to have also however it shows this one...

[image]

Comment: Don't have anywhere to input that.  Just have one option to choose the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably only set the icon for the application, not the icon for your *form*. Each form can have its own icon.

Answer (score 0):

The shell display the icon of windows, not of executalbles, you need to select an icon for the window that is displayed.

In WPF the default icon for a window is the icon of the application, but it seem to only work in Release (See [WPF Icon for all app windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881580/wpf-icon-for-all-app-windows) ) without a debugger attached. You could still set the [icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.icon.aspx) property of the window to what you want (Directly or from a resource, as you wish):

```
<Window
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  Icon="SomeIcon.ico">
</Window>
```

In winforms the designer is the simpler way to do it as it wil automaticaly put it in a resource file or let you select from an existing resource. If you want to to it by hand see [Form.Icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.icon) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your form
Go to the properties window, go to Icon, select your ccon from the Resources

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the icon for each form.