# How can I change the Icon of WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF Icon for all app windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881580/wpf-icon-for-all-app-windows)

I have a `wpf` application, I want to set the icon for all the windows.

I have and `ico` file in my project folder /img/app.ico, but it is `build action = Resource`.

I change the application `Icon and manifest` to `/img/app.ico`, but it won't work.

An error is prompt when compiling:

```
The img/app.ico is not found.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881580/wpf-icon-for-all-app-windows

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried to force icon

```
<Window Icon="youricon.ico"></Window>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.icon.aspx

Comment: This works nicely. Remember to add the image to your Visual Studio project, or else it will not be able to find it's embedded resource.