# How to change the Application Icon?

Tags: c#, wpf, icons

[How to: Specify an Application Icon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/339stzf7.aspx) **And** [WPF: How to add an icon for entire application](http://www.broculos.net/2014/03/wpf-how-to-add-icon-for-entire.html#.VzoGLZErKhc) **And** [Setting Icon for wpf application (VS 08)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672537/setting-icon-for-wpf-application-vs-08) **And** [WPF Icon for all app windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881580/wpf-icon-for-all-app-windows) are leading to the same procedure:

- Right click project
- Go to Properties
- Go to Application tab
- set it under Application Icon

However, it is still not working for me. There was an old icon, I changed it using the above procedure but the application is still showing the old icon. I restarted everything. I executed as *Release* and *Debug* also as *Start Without Debugging*. Still showing the old icon. Any ideas?

Comment: try to remove all files from bin and obj directory and rebuild project.

Comment: @uriel Yup and I tried that. Sorry forgot to mention. Rebuild, Clean, Delete then Build. Still..

Comment: Google "reset shell icon cache".

Answer (score 0):

Look here:
[WPF Icon for all app windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881580/wpf-icon-for-all-app-windows)

From the first answer of the above question:

> "A liitle tip : if you set the application icon and expect to see it
>   on the window - it wont show up if running in debug from VS. Running
>   externally or without attaching (ctrl + f5) the icon displays as
>   expected."

Comment: It did not show the new icon. Neither Externally and/or internally, nor Release or/and Debug